CORS policy blocking when using Google Speech-to-Text through Google Cloud Functions (javascript call)
The function should start recording when a button is pressed, and this sends to Google Cloud Functions (I'm using a shared server so I can't run node.js on it) which handles the Speech-to-Text API. The code in the function (packages are correctly included externally):
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const cors = require('cors');

// Set CORS options
const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'https://example.com', // Allow your website's origin
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // For legacy browser support
};

exports.transcribeAudio = (req, res) => {
    // Apply CORS with the options
    cors(corsOptions)(req, res, async () => {
        if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
            // Send response to OPTIONS requests and return immediately
            res.status(204).send('');
            return;
        }

        // Your endpoint logic for POST requests
        const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
        const audio = req.body.audio;
        const audioBytes = audio.replace('data:audio/webm;codecs=opus;base64,', '');

        const request = {
            audio: { content: audioBytes },
            config: {
                encoding: 'WEBM_OPUS',
                sampleRateHertz: 16000,
                languageCode: 'en-US',
            },
        };

        try {
            const [response] = await client.recognize(request);
            const transcription = response.results
                .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
                .join('\n');
            res.status(200).send({ transcription });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
            res.status(500).send('Failed to transcribe audio');
        }
    });
};


The console error is:

Access to fetch at
'https://europe-west2-xxxxxxxxxx-420512.cloudfunctions.net/Speech-to-Text'
from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The function is set to accept all traffic, and there are allUsers permissions to invoke the function.
I have no idea where I'm going wrong after a ton of trying...
I have experimented with a variety of CORS options, but nothing I've done works for this error.
